# Django get weeks from model date to today

Tags: python, django, date, model

I want to get how many weeks it is from a date (that is stored in the .db) from todays date.
I tried to work with many answers from the web but can't seem to get it to produce correctly.
Most common error I get when trying stuff out is

```
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'QuerySet' and 'datetime.date'
```

The class in models.py

```
class ADown(models.Model):
    Aname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    dateStart = models.DateTimeField('date start')
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.Aname
```

Within views.py - I feel like it's because I'm not really correctly referencing 'dateStart' from the .all()

```
from django.utils import timezone
from ADown.models import Adown
import datetime

def index(request):

d1 = ADown.objects.all()
totalweeks = (d1 - datetime.date.today()).TotalDays / 7
print totalweeks
latest_poll_list = ADown.objects.order_by('-dateStart')[:5]
template = loader.get_template('ADown/index.html')
context = RequestContext(request, {
    'latest_poll_list': latest_poll_list,
    'totalweek': totalweeks,
    'todays': datetime.now(),
})
return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

And how I call it in .html

```
</thead>
<tbody>
{% for ADown in latest_poll_list %}
    <tr>
        <td><a>{{ ADown.AName }}</a></td>
        <td><a>{{ totalweek }}</a></td>
        <td><a>{{ ADown.dateStart }}</a></td>
    </tr>
{% empty %}
        <li><a>Something wrong!</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
{% if latest_poll_list %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're  taking all **ADown** objects (queryset object) in your database and substracting the number of weeks of the current month. You must to refer to dateStart in d1 variable to do this.

queryset in this case **ADown.objects.all()** isn't a valid datetype wich you can operate with a datetime object **datetime.date.today()**.

Comment: How do I correctly reference dateStart
ADown.object.get('dateStart')?

Comment: You can do this a = ADown.objects.all() then iterate over a list using a for. `for i in a: `

Comment: @user1043816 You can do this a = ADown.objects.all() then iterate over the list using a for. `for i in a: i.dateStart ` then you can compare every ADown object dateStart field  with today date to get the number of weeks. However, you shouldn't use datetime, instead timezone.now() to the comparation

Comment: How could I get it to do this for each dateStart - right now it's only doing the first entry. Would I have to make a model?